# Start with IF statement in Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to select rows in a subquery with an `IF` condition:

```
DECLARE @VersionNo varchar(30)
SET @VersionNo = 'Hello'
SELECT (
    CASE @VersionNo WHEN 'Hello' 
        THEN (SELECT '22','22') 
        ELSE (SELECT '25','22') 
    END)
```

But I am getting this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword '`IF`'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword '`Then`'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword '`Else`'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near '`)`'.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Based on the answers, I have changed my query to:

```
DECLARE @VersionNo varchar(30)
SET @VersionNo = 'Hello'
SELECT (
    CASE @VersionNo WHEN 'Hello' 
        THEN (SELECT '22','22') 
        ELSE (SELECT '25','22') 
    END)
```

Now I am getting this error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `CASE`, you cannot use `IF` in a select query

```
select case @VersionNo when 'Hello' 
    then 'Yes' 
    else 'No' 
end
```

Alternatively, you can do this to run different select queries based on the value of your variable:

```
IF @VersionNo = 'Hello' 
    SELECT 'Yes'
ELSE
    SELECT 'No'
```

Comment: select (case @VersionNo when 'Hello' then (Select '22','22') else (Select '25','22') end)

Comment: @kombsh Ok, check out another version in my answer.

Comment: ok thanks, thats what I need... simple thing.. but hard time to think (::

Answer (score 2):

Use `CASE WHEN`:

```
declare @VersionNo varchar(30);
Set @VersionNo = 'Hello';

Select CASE WHEN @VersionNo='Hello' Then 'Yes' Else 'No' END AS SomeCol;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this one :

```
DECLARE @VersionNo VARCHAR(30)
SET @VersionNo = 'Hello'
SELECT  CASE @VersionNo
          WHEN 'Hello' THEN '22'
          ELSE '25'
        END ,
        CASE @VersionNo
          WHEN 'Hello' THEN '22'
          ELSE '22'
        END
```

Comment: Yup, just made a post doing the same thing, but this is right. Far as I know, you can't return two columns in a single case statement, so using two cases for each output column you want is the way to go.